# Capitalization of "Internet"

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns, writing-style

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should the words “internet” and “web” be capitalized?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/644/should-the-words-internet-and-web-be-capitalized)

For the most part *Internet* is capitalized, less frequently it occurs uncapitalized.  Is this a style issue or is one considered more correct.

Subjectively, would the average reader consider using the uncapitalized version to be a mistake / display of poor English?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Internet should be capitalised, because it's a proper noun and defines a single, definite thing not something general (like the word *tree*, for example).

If you look up the word, you'll find it always capitalised, I can link you to the [OALD](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/internet), as an example.

If you're writing in some informal context, most people won't mind if you write it lowercase, though. But if we consider some official context, for example writing your Curriculum Vitae, you would write it properly.

**EDIT:** After Garet's comment, I decided to introduce a distinction. If you want to refer to a general inter-network (which by the way, it's the compound where "*Internet*" comes from) or if you want to use the same term to refer to something which is not the World Wide Internet, then it would be written lowercase.

Comment: +1 good answer. Something to add but I think this is the right answer so I'll put it here. There's a difference in capitalization for 'the Internet' and, say, an internet between two partner organizations. The former being the "normal" Internet and the latter usually being two inter-connected *intra* nets.

Comment: @Garet Claborn: You're right, I didn't thought of making the distiction since his doubts were basically about the Internet we all know... :D

Comment: True, true. I just wanted to say it so no one would someday read this question and go violently accost unsuspecting writers of 'an internet'. ;P

Comment: Can the person who downvoted explain why? Thanks.

Comment: @Alenanno, that logic is not airtight. For example, "web browser" is lowercase, which is software for browsing the "World Wide Web", capitalized. There is only one web, yet it's capitalization is variable. The [rules](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/about16_rules.html) have changed over time. Eventually, it may be that the Internet would go the way of Television and Radio (which were originally capitalized). Some publishers lowercase internet. It's a convention, with plausible reasons, but a convention nonetheless.

Comment: @PaulDraper That might be because "web browser" is a common noun, not a proper noun. The actual web browsers are capitalized though. I think that's the difference there. :D But yeah, I think that "internet" might lose the capital and probably it's already happening.

Comment: How do you know *the Internet* is a proper noun? Why don't we capitalize *the Sky*?

Comment: "The world" is not capitalised, and there is only one. Also "the universe" and many more counterexamples. If it was truly a proper noun, it wouldn't need "the". Compare "God" with "a god". You don't say "the Dave", just "Dave". You never use "the" with a proper noun, except humorously. Capitalisation is used to make a noun important, e.g. "the Queen". When the internet first became available to the public it was big. It's not so big anymore because it's become part of our lives.

Answer (score 6):

An *internet* is simply a network of networks. *The Internet* is the worldwide TCP/IP-based internet that we all share.

Usually, you'll want to avoid the generic lowercase usage, to avoid confusion.

Comment: +1 - *internet* can also be used (without capitalization) to describe something (ie. an *internet-ready computer*)

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it is becoming less and less common to write "Internet", as if it were a proper noun. Indeed, the use of the phrasing "the internet" tends to indicate that "internet" is not a proper noun, because if it were, the word "the" would be redundant.

The proportion of people who are familiar with the origin of "the internet" as a proper noun, or indeed to who understand that the phenomenological features of the internet qualify it as being capable of having a proper noun, seems to be dwindling. My guess is that most people think of the internet as being like the telephone system or the air - a thing that lacks either unity, number, or identity.